# Is the following derived MAC where the output is XOR'ed with the key secure?

Tags: encryption, symmetric, mac, authenticated-encryption, pseudo-random-function

Hey I'm wondering if the following scheme is secure or not , I tried reductions and some tries to prove that it not must be secure but I feel completely stuck .

More details:
It's just any reduction that came to my mind (up to my knowledge) required knowing $k$ . I tried to use the 'classic' technique of trying to simulate somehow the original Mac and get into a contradiction of it being insecure itself (which is known to be secure in this question)

$\forall k\in\{0,1\}^{n},m\in\mathbb{M}$ $Mac_{k}^{'}(m)$ is defined
as follows:
$Mac_{k}^{'}(m)=Mac_{k}(m) \oplus k$ it's known that $Mac_{k}$ is secure
note: $\mathbb{M}$ is the message space and it's assumed that the key $k$ is generated by some $\operatorname{Gen}$ algorithm in a random manner.  It is asked to prove or disprove that $Mac_{k}^{'}(m)$ is  necessarily secure.

Comment: "it is asked" and "not homework" are at odds to each other, Doron. The initial question even had a copy of the assignment. I removed the latter statement that it is not homework. The way it is asked the community should at least treat it as such.

Comment: Hint: Can you imagine a MAC which is by itself secure (though perhaps a bit "artificial") that would leak the key when used in this construction?

Comment: @SEJPM Iv'e tried for all day long with no success . Are u sure such  construction exist ?

Comment: @DoronBruder the example you described in a previous edit + comment did work. I'm not sure why you think otherwise now?

Comment: @SEJPM it does not work as this way I could only reveal half of the key which alone does not finish the proof . I got really stuck there

Comment: @DoronBruder Hint: if you want to leak the entire key, can you somehow exploit the abilitiy to make multiple queries?

Comment: @SEJPM nope , not really , at least not with the construction I tried before . As adding 0^n/2 instead of half of the output or anything to one of the half sides will only discover half of the key ... note that both functions are from {0,1}^n to {0,1}^n

Comment: Well, can you perhaps move the zeroes around based on the queries?

Comment: I think I can! add zeros in either sides based on the m (inputs), when it's enough to add zero the one of the sides only for specific m and otherwise add zero the second side

Comment: You just beat me by a few seconds :) I think that's enough hints? Note that you could also switch based on the resulting MAC value although that's slightly more tricky. Also note that revealing even part of the key means that the algorithm is not as secure as it is supposed to be - leaking half of the key is enough to consider it broken.

Comment: Side but related remark: if $P$ is a random-like public permutation of $\{0,1\}^n$, efficiently computable in both directions, what can you say about $k\in\{0,1\}^n$ given $P(k)\oplus k$?